# Application that checks text files on startup doesn't find text files when started through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe

Running the .bat file pasted below creates the text files needed by the application to operate, however when the application is started through the START line in the .bat file, my application notifies me that these files do not exist. However this is not the case, as if I were to the run the application through opening the .exe myself, I have no issues.

Here is the .bat file.

```
pushd %~dp0
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "GetInstalledPrograms.ps1"

@ECHO OFF
SET InstalledProgramNames="InstalledProgramNames.txt"
SET InstalledProgramNames6432Node="InstalledProgramNames6432Node.txt"
SET InstalledProgramVersions="InstalledProgramVersions.txt"
SET InstalledProgramVersions6432Node="InstalledProgramVersions6432Node.txt"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST %InstalledProgramNames% IF EXIST %InstalledProgramNames6432Node% IF EXIST %InstalledProgramVersions% IF EXIST %InstalledProgramVersions6432Node% GOTO FoundIt

REM If we get here, the file is not found.

REM Wait 5 seconds and then recheck.
REM If no delay is needed, comment/remove the timeout line.
TIMEOUT /T 5 >nul

GOTO CheckForFile

:FoundIt
ECHO Found: %InstalledProgramNames%
ECHO Found: %InstalledProgramNames6432Node%
ECHO Found: %InstalledProgramVersions%
ECHO Found: %InstalledProgramVersions6432Node%

REM Change this when releasing - it wont be debug
START "" "bin\Debug\NIThirdPartySoftwareChecker.exe"
```

EDIT: The .ps1 file as requested.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName | Out-File -filepath  InstalledProgramNames6432Node.txt
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName | Out-File -filepath  InstalledProgramNames.txt
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayVersion | Out-File -filepath  InstalledProgramVersions6432Node.txt
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayVersion | Out-File -filepath  InstalledProgramVersions.txt
```

Comment: Your opening line states, 'Running the `.bat` file pasted below creates the text files needed by the application to operate', however there is nothing in that code to indicate that any files are created. I'm assuming that the `PowerShell` script attempts to read the registry to parse the registry uninstall key(s), so that may create one or more files, listing the installed programs found. Perhaps if we were to see the `.ps1` and `.txt` files, we'd have a better idea of what your issue may be! You can do that by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55042420/edit) accordingly.

Comment: @Compo Edited. Thanks for the response.

Comment: We don't know anything about your executable program, so have no idea if it uses a specific or current directory for searching for the files. As you've specifically asked for the batch script directory to be current at the outset, I'd have to assume that all of the four files would be output to the same directory as the batch file. If they do indeed sit there then the likely scenario is that your executable is looking for them some place else, _(probably its own directory)_. If you do actually need to use `Start`, _(unknown)_, I would probably suggest you investigate its `/D` option first.